# Angular Material 2 dialog with form test failing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-material, dialog

I have a simple login dialog that is generated using Angular Material 2
and an Angular reactive form.
The dialog box works as is should when used in a program but the unit testing for it doesn't reflect this.  The forms login button should be disabled until both the name and password fields pass the validation criteria set up in the component at which point the login button is enabled and available for clicking.
However, when I run the test and set the name and input fields to valid content the login button remains disabled and the test fails.
The relevant section of code for the test is as follows

```
  it('should enable the login button when a valid username and password are entered', fakeAsync(() => {
    (overlayContainerElement.querySelector('input[formcontrolname="name"]') as HTMLInputElement).value = 'ABC';
    (overlayContainerElement.querySelector('input[formcontrolname="password"]') as HTMLInputElement).value = '12345678';
    viewContainerFixture.detectChanges();
    tick();

    viewContainerFixture.detectChanges();
    const loginBtn = overlayContainerElement.querySelector('button[md-raised-button]');
    const nameInput = overlayContainerElement.querySelector('input[formcontrolname="name"]');
    const passwordInput = overlayContainerElement.querySelector('input[formcontrolname="password"]');
    console.log('Login Button is:', loginBtn.textContent);
    console.log('Login Button is:', loginBtn.getAttribute('ng-reflect-disabled'));

    expect((nameInput as HTMLInputElement).value).toEqual('ABC');
    expect((passwordInput as HTMLInputElement).value).toEqual('12345678');
    expect((overlayContainerElement.querySelector('button[md-raised-button]')).getAttribute('ng-reflect-disabled')).toBe('false');
  }));
```

I am obviously not refreshing the state of the login button but cannot see why this is so.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

[https://plnkr.co/edit/U1lpoa?p=info](https://plnkr.co/edit/U1lpoa?p=info/%20Login%20Test%20Sample%22) is a link to a plunker which shows the component and test suite and the code is reproduced below.

**Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { MdDialog, MdDialogRef } from '@angular/material';


@Component({
  selector: 'lpa-login-dialog',
  templateUrl: './login-dialog.component.html',
})
export class LoginDialogComponent implements OnInit {
  loginForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private dlgRef: MdDialogRef<LoginDialogComponent>
  ) {
    this.createForm()
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  private createForm() {
    this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]]
    })
  }

  public login() {
    this.dlgRef.close(this.loginForm.value.name);
  }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<h1 class="mdl-dialog-title" style="text-align: center">App Login</h1>

<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="login()" ngnovalidate>
  <div class="mdl-dialog-content">
    <div class="form-group">
      <md-input-container style="width: 100%">
        <input mdInput class="form-control" formControlName="name" placeholder="Name">
      </md-input-container>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <md-input-container style="width: 100%">
        <input mdInput type="password" class="form-control" formControlName="password" placeholder="Password">
      </md-input-container>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="mdl-dialog-actions" style="text-align: center">
    <button md-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid" >Login</button>
    <button md-button md-dialog-close=false color="warn">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Unit Test (.spec)**

```
import { inject, async, fakeAsync, flushMicrotasks, ComponentFixture, TestBed, tick, } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { NgModule, Component, Directive, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, Injector, Inject, DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

import { NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { MaterialModule, MdDialogModule, MdDialog, MdDialogRef, MdButton, OverlayContainer } from '@angular/material';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subscriber } from 'rxjs/Subscriber';

import { LoginDialogComponent } from './login-dialog.component';

// helper classes
// tslint:disable-next-line:directive-selector
@Directive({ selector: 'dir-with-view-container' })
class DlgTestViewContainerDirective {
  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'lpa-arbitrary-component',
  template: `<dir-with-view-container></dir-with-view-container>`,
})
class DlgTestChildViewContainerComponent {
  @ViewChild(DlgTestViewContainerDirective) childWithViewContainer: DlgTestViewContainerDirective;

  get childViewContainer() {
    return this.childWithViewContainer.viewContainerRef;
  }
}

// Create a real (non-test) NgModule as a workaround for
// https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10760
const TEST_DIRECTIVES = [
  DlgTestViewContainerDirective,
  DlgTestChildViewContainerComponent,
  LoginDialogComponent
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MdDialogModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    NoopAnimationsModule
  ],
  exports: TEST_DIRECTIVES,
  declarations: TEST_DIRECTIVES,
  entryComponents: [
    LoginDialogComponent
  ]
})
class DialogTestModule { }

describe('Login Dialog Component', () => {

  let dialog: MdDialog;
  let dialogRef: MdDialogRef<LoginDialogComponent>;

  let overlayContainerElement: HTMLElement;

  let viewContainerFixture: ComponentFixture<DlgTestChildViewContainerComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        DialogTestModule,
     ],
      declarations: [
      ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: OverlayContainer, useFactory: () => {
            overlayContainerElement = document.createElement('div');
            return { getContainerElement: () => overlayContainerElement };
          }
        }
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(inject([MdDialog], (d: MdDialog) => {
    dialog = d;
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    viewContainerFixture = TestBed.createComponent(DlgTestChildViewContainerComponent);
    viewContainerFixture.detectChanges();

    dialogRef = dialog.open(LoginDialogComponent);
    viewContainerFixture.detectChanges();

  });

  it('should be created', fakeAsync(() => {
    expect(dialogRef.componentInstance instanceof LoginDialogComponent).toBe(true, 'Failed to open');
    expect(overlayContainerElement.querySelector('h1').innerText).toEqual('App Login');

    dialogRef.close();
    tick(500);
    viewContainerFixture.detectChanges();
  }));

  it('should close and return false when cancel button pressed', async(() => {
    const afterCloseCallback = jasmine.createSpy('afterClose callback');

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(afterCloseCallback);
    (overlayContainerElement.querySelector('button[md-dialog-close="false"]') as HTMLElement).click();
    viewContainerFixture.detectChanges();

    viewContainerFixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(overlayContainerElement.querySelector('md-dialog-container')).toBeNull('Dialog box still open');
      expect(afterCloseCallback).toHaveBeenCalledWith('false');
    });
  }));

  describe('should disable login button', () => {
    it('without a user and password entry', fakeAsync(() => {

      const btn = overlayContainerElement.querySelector('button[md-raised-button]');
      expect(btn.getAttribute('ng-reflect-disabled')).toBe('true');

      dialogRef.close()
      tick(500);
      viewContainerFixture.detectChanges();
    }));

    it('with a user entry but without a password entry', async(() => {

      (overlayContainerElement.querySelector('input[formcontrolname="name"]') as HTMLInputElement).value = 'DD';
      viewContainerFixture.detectChanges();

      viewContainerFixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        viewContainerFixture.detectChanges();
        const nameInput = overlayContainerElement.querySelector('input[formcontrolname="name"]');
        const passwordInput = overlayContainerElement.querySelector('input[formcontrolname="password"]');

        expect((nameInput as HTMLInputElement).value).toEqual('DD');
        expect((passwordInput as HTMLInputElement).value).toEqual('');
        expect((overlayContainerElement.querySelector('button[md-raised-button]')).getAttribute('ng-reflect-disabled')).toBe('true');
      });
    }));

    it('with a password but without a user entry', async(() => {

      (overlayContainerElement.querySelector('input[formcontrolname="password"]') as HTMLInputElement).value = 'Password';
      viewContainerFixture.detectChanges();

      viewContainerFixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        viewContainerFixture.detectChanges();
        const nameInput = overlayContainerElement.querySelector('input[formcontrolname="name"]');
        const passwordInput = overlayContainerElement.querySelector('input[formcontrolname="password"]');

        expect((nameInput as HTMLInputElement).value).toEqual('');
        expect((passwordInput as HTMLInputElement).value).toEqual('Password');
        expect((overlayContainerElement.querySelector('button[md-raised-button]')).getAttribute('ng-reflect-disabled')).toBe('true');
      });
    }));

    it('with a valid user name but invalid password', async(() => {

      (overlayContainerElement.querySelector('input[formcontrolname="name"]') as HTMLInputElement).value = 'ABC';
      (overlayContainerElement.querySelector('input[formcontrolname="password"]') as HTMLInputElement).value = '1234567';
      viewContainerFixture.detectChanges();

      viewContainerFixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        viewContainerFixture.detectChanges();
        const nameInput = overlayContainerElement.querySelector('input[formcontrolname="name"]');
        const passwordInput = overlayContainerElement.querySelector('input[formcontrolname="password"]');

        expect((nameInput as HTMLInputElement).value).toEqual('ABC');
        expect((passwordInput as HTMLInputElement).value).toEqual('1234567');
        expect((overlayContainerElement.querySelector('button[md-raised-button]')).getAttribute('ng-reflect-disabled')).toBe('true');
      });
    }));

    it('with an invalid user name but with a valid password', async(() => {

      (overlayContainerElement.querySelector('input[formcontrolname="name"]') as HTMLInputElement).value = 'AB';
      (overlayContainerElement.querySelector('input[formcontrolname="password"]') as HTMLInputElement).value = '12345678';
      viewContainerFixture.detectChanges();

      viewContainerFixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        viewContainerFixture.detectChanges();
        const nameInput = overlayContainerElement.querySelector('input[formcontrolname="name"]');
        const passwordInput = overlayContainerElement.querySelector('input[formcontrolname="password"]');

        expect((nameInput as HTMLInputElement).value).toEqual('AB');
        expect((passwordInput as HTMLInputElement).value).toEqual('12345678');
        expect((overlayContainerElement.querySelector('button[md-raised-button]')).getAttribute('ng-reflect-disabled')).toBe('true');
      });
    }));
  });

  it('should enable the login button when a valid username and password are entered', fakeAsync(() => {
    (overlayContainerElement.querySelector('input[formcontrolname="name"]') as HTMLInputElement).value = 'ABC';
    (overlayContainerElement.querySelector('input[formcontrolname="password"]') as HTMLInputElement).value = '12345678';
    viewContainerFixture.detectChanges();
    tick();

    viewContainerFixture.detectChanges();
    const loginBtn = overlayContainerElement.querySelector('button[md-raised-button]');
    const nameInput = overlayContainerElement.querySelector('input[formcontrolname="name"]');
    const passwordInput = overlayContainerElement.querySelector('input[formcontrolname="password"]');
    console.log('Login Button is:', loginBtn.textContent);
    console.log('Login Button is:', loginBtn.getAttribute('ng-reflect-disabled'));

    expect((nameInput as HTMLInputElement).value).toEqual('ABC');
    expect((passwordInput as HTMLInputElement).value).toEqual('12345678');
    expect((overlayContainerElement.querySelector('button[md-raised-button]')).getAttribute('ng-reflect-disabled')).toBe('false');
  }));

  it('should enable the login button when a valid username and password are entered', async(() => {
    (overlayContainerElement.querySelector('input[formcontrolname="name"]') as HTMLInputElement).value = 'ABC';
    (overlayContainerElement.querySelector('input[formcontrolname="password"]') as HTMLInputElement).value = '12345678';
    viewContainerFixture.detectChanges();

    viewContainerFixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      viewContainerFixture.detectChanges();
      const loginBtn = overlayContainerElement.querySelector('button[md-raised-button]');
      const nameInput = overlayContainerElement.querySelector('input[formcontrolname="name"]');
      const passwordInput = overlayContainerElement.querySelector('input[formcontrolname="password"]');
      console.log('Login Button is:', loginBtn.textContent);
      console.log('Login Button is:', loginBtn.getAttribute('ng-reflect-disabled'));

      expect((nameInput as HTMLInputElement).value).toEqual('ABC');
      expect((passwordInput as HTMLInputElement).value).toEqual('12345678');
      expect((overlayContainerElement.querySelector('button[md-raised-button]')).getAttribute('ng-reflect-disabled')).toBe('false');
    });
  }));
});
```

Comment: why are you using `overlayContainerElement` as HTML element. the component instance must be used to get any HTMLElement.

Comment: Aravind - I had a lot of problem setting up this test as it is creating a dialog box.  To get over this most of the test framework is copied from the dialog test module of the angular material 2 source on github.  That seems to be the way they do it so I thought it best to follow their method. Will try changing it in my private plunker and see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

OK, now I feel a fool as I concentrated so much on getting the dialog box to run in a test environment I forgot to tell the form to update!
All I needed was to add the dispatchEvent call to the input boxes.  My new code is (with a little bit of tidying up) :

```
  it('should enable the login button when a valid username and password are entered', async(() => {
    const loginBtn = overlayContainerElement.querySelector('button[md-raised-button]') as HTMLButtonElement;
    const nameInput = overlayContainerElement.querySelector('input[formcontrolname="name"]') as HTMLInputElement;
    const passwordInput = overlayContainerElement.querySelector('input[formcontrolname="password"]') as HTMLInputElement;
    nameInput.value = 'ABC';
    nameInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    passwordInput.value = '12345678';
    passwordInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    viewContainerFixture.detectChanges();

    viewContainerFixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      viewContainerFixture.detectChanges();
      expect(nameInput.value).toEqual('ABC');
      expect(passwordInput.value).toEqual('12345678');
      expect(loginBtn.getAttribute('ng-reflect-disabled')).toBe('false', 'Login button disabled should now be false');
    });
  }));
```